# Borrowing fields of a struct independently inside a closure

Tags: rust

What's the difference between

```rust
let book_scores = &system.book_scores;
library.books.sort_unstable_by_key(|b| book_scores[*b]);
```

and

```rust
library.books.sort_unstable_by_key(|b| &system.book_scores[*b]);
```

?

The first one is allowed by the compiler and the second one fails with

> error[E0502]: cannot borrow `system` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable

`libraries` is a field of `system`, `library` is an element of `libraries` in a for loop like
`for library in &mut system.libraries {`

Comment: Please post the rest of the code and little bit of definitions for structures would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that a closure's variable binding is shallow. Consider the following closure:

```rust
let closure = || println!("{}", a.b.c.d);
```

Since the closure doesn't define an `a`, `a` is borrowed from its outside environment. When actually called, the closure accesses `.b.c.d` on the borrowed `a`.

The closure doesn't try to immediately calculate `a.b.c.d` and borrow that. If it did, it wouldn't be able to notice changes to `a.b` or `a.b.c` or even `a.b.c.d`. Similarly, if it captured `a.b.c` on creation and accessed `.d` when called, it wouldn't be able to respond to changes to `a.b` or `a.b.c`.

If you need to pre-capture a part of the expression, you need to make it explicit, as your first snippet does.